# Safari browser xlsx download not working, instead opening blob in a new tab

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, angular6, filesaver.js

I am using fileSaver.js for angular to download xlsx file from API. it's working for all browsers except IOS Safari. Safari is opening the file in a new tab instead of downloading it. In Safari, i can see options to save the file but the name becomes "unknown.xlsx". But in IOS Chrome, i can't see any download options either.

My Typescript:

```
    let cd = resposne.headers.get("content-disposition");
    //get the file name with regex
    let regex = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/;
    let match = regex.exec(cd);
    //is there a file name?
    let fileName = match[1] || "answers";
    //replace leading and trailing slashes that C# added to your file name
    fileName = fileName.replace(/\"/g, "");
    let blob = resposne.body;

    // Using fileSaver.js for fixing safari file download error.
    // This plugin supports all modern browser for downloading files from API
    saveAs(blob, fileName);
```

Is there any way to download the excel file directly from IOS Safari or chrome?

Comment: First, you need to send the file with content-disposition `attachment` otherwise the browser will try to show the content if possible, second you need to send the proper mime type,  that's `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet` for xlsx and `application/vnd.ms-excel` for xls for the browser to recognize the file type and offer the user appropriate settings (user can override if its downloaded, opened or asked). If you don't know it use `application/octet-stream` (which is generic mime type for binary files). In your question its unclear what you have done so far

Comment: Also the JS script downloading doesn't work everywhere. Why don't you just open the requesting link as url and let the browser handle it?